# PHP SQL row count

Tags: php, mysql

I want to make a login for a class (so I'm not looking into preventing SQL injections right now) and I'm having trouble making use of the row counting to see if I can login or not.

How could I count the rows from the selection? I've tried some things which just didn't work.

The error I get is in the line that has a comment.

```
$host = "localhost";
$serverusername = "root";
$serverpassword = "";
$database = "usuarios";
$table = "user";

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $serverusername, $serverpassword, $database);
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE `username` = ".$username." AND `password` = ".$password;


$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$row = $result -> num_rows; //this line has an error. Trying to get property of non-object 

if ($row != 0)
{
header('Location : index.html');
die();
}
else
{
    echo "password incorrecta!";
}


$mysqli -> close();
```

Comment: Your code contains syntax errors. 
Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Password is probably a string. And see about prepared statements

Comment: To prevent your code from SQL injection, use [PDO::prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php)

Comment: @RajdeepPaul Probably shouldn't mix PDO and MySQLi, [`$mysqli->prepare`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) would fit better here ;)

Comment: I've used php with this same syntax of error and it worked.

Hold on, I'm posting the exact error in the first post.

Comment: @Qirel Yes, of course. Either `mysqli_` or `PDO` extension will do. I was just stating an option. :)

Comment: @Strawberry hehe, yeah. One hopes it would be, especially a "hashed" one at best ;-)

Comment: *"How could I count the rows from the selection?"* - Kind of unclear here. If you're trying to get a "count" as you state here, then you need to use `COUNT()`. If you're wanting to check if a user exists with the password given; again... your code contains syntax errors. Your question as it stands, is off-topic for a few reasons. 1) Syntax errors. 2) Unclear.

Comment: if username = 123 and password = 456, great. Otherwise: they're strings.

Comment: I have fixed the way the string is in the query.

$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'";

Previously it put the username and password without 's or "s.

I still have trouble with the counting. I'm gonna try the COUNT thing in SQL now

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't think this is a duplicate, it's not related to the use of single .... I think it's a debugging problem

Comment: Moderator I found out what the real error is...... I mistyped my database name. Please delete. Sorry everyone it all works now.

Comment: You can't delete? Not enough rep?

Comment: it says it has answers so I can't delete it

Answer (score 1):

You need to put **$username** and **$password** in quotes:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'";
```

This code is vulnerable to SQL injection.

Comment: $table doesn't need to be in quotes?

Comment: No, $table does not need to be in quotes.

Comment: I still get the exact same problem though. I've edited the first post please check the line with the commentary, thanks

Comment: nor does username or password column.

Comment: @Dagon is correct, the backticks on the username and password column names are not required.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have error reporting set to on (because you provide the error given) your next step is to troubleshoot the query or the output.

To see what is wrong with your query try debugging it Here's how I debug query's

1. echo the query to the screen

   ```
   $query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE `username` = ".$username." AND `password` = ".$password;
   echo $query;
   ```
2. copy the printed query from the screen
3. execute the query in you db manager (phpmyadmin)
4. Read the sql error and
5. change your query accordingly

If the query gives the correct output, then the problem it with the code that is run after you're query. otherwise you have to add your sql error here, so we can fix.

**sidenote:**

shouldn't `$row = $result -> num_rows;` be `$row = $result->num_rows;` (not sure if it matters, the extra space)

**note 2: after reading the comments**

Probably you're password is stored "hashed" and right now you're querying as is (not "hashed"). Depending how you hashed the password in your db you should hash the password post accordingly.

Comment: Alright, I have fixed the query.

$query = "SELECT * FROM ".$table." WHERE `username` = '".$username."' AND `password` = '".$password."'";

This makes it so the parameters are read as strings in the query. But I still am troubled that the num_rows thing isn't working.

Comment: have you followed all the steps I placed for you? execute the printed query to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: Yes I have followed every step. I even use phpmyadmin aswell. And there was an error.

Went from SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE `username` = Rob AND `password` = no
....TO...


SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user WHERE `username` = 'Rob' AND `password` = 'no'

Notice the '' to classify them as strings

Comment: not sure why you use `select count()`, while you could use `select *` . If you explicitly want to use only the number of rows in your code you could use `select count(*)`

Comment: is the password actually no? or is the password empty?

Comment: oh sorry, the count was when I was trying something else, pay no mind to it.

Comment: do you get a query result or not?